# Having issues with PHP hash('sha256', 'x') not matching a bash command

Tags: php, hash

How can I do the following using PHP's hash() function? I've tried and failed (see much lower php code)

```
echo -n '807542FB6685F9FD8F37D56FAF62F0BB4563684A51539E4B26F0840DB361E0027C' | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b
```

The above bash line gives the following output:

```
7DE4708EB23AB611371BB778FC0C8BDE80394AB2D8704D7129FB5771E2F1730D
```

This php code doesn't quite do it:

```
<?php
echo hash('sha256', '807542FB6685F9FD8F37D56FAF62F0BB4563684A51539E4B26F0840DB361E0027C');
```

outputs:

```
e50f2ac6f7b6a2cbf640f44806affe06a330eb655f9e97bf70d5e09274340e4b
```

Comment: You're decoding the hex string to binary on the commandline using `xxd`. But you're not piping same binary string to PHPs `hash()` function. It does not auto-decode the hex text.

Comment: right, how would I do the same in PHP?

Comment: `hex2bin`, if you have PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code was you were missing the php equivalent for `xxd -r`. You can get this by using `pack("H*", $string)`:

```
echo hash('sha256', pack("H*", '807542FB6685F9FD8F37D56FAF62F0BB4563684A51539E4B26F0840DB361E0027C'));
```

Or, if you have PHP 5.4 or greater, you can use `hex2bin()`:

```
echo hash('sha256', hex2bin('807542FB6685F9FD8F37D56FAF62F0BB4563684A51539E4B26F0840DB361E0027C'));
```

The output with both of these is:

> 7de4708eb23ab611371bb778fc0c8bde80394ab2d8704d7129fb5771e2f1730d